# Как получить название функции, которая совершила вызов данной функции?

Tags: c

Пишу лабораторную работу, нужно логирование, и для того чтобы не запутываться, хотелось бы иметь в логах что-то вроде:

> Error: init_link - not enough memory

Сейчас ничего, кроме передачи в логгер строки-названия функции, в голову не приходит. Есть ли более изящный метод?

Update:
Вот что я имею в виду:

```
int foo(int bar)
{
    int foobar = -1;
    check_something(foobar/bar);
    return foobar/bar;
}
```

Теперь в check_something должен вызваться логгер, в котором сказано о том, что check_something был вызван из foo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вопрос очень интересный, попробую предложить решение, хотя не уверен, то ли это, что видится автору вопроса.

На мой взгляд, хороший логгер должен выводить весь путь вызовов к точке вывода
сообщения, наподобие вывода команды where в интерактивном отладчике gdb .

В принципе, такую информацию можно извлечь, совместно рассматривая стек выполнения
(там адреса возврата) и таблицу символов загрузочного модуля (там есть адреса точек входа в функции и их имена (конечно, если модуль не стрипнут). Для лабораторки это, конечно, крутовато.

Можно, наверное, предложить 'ручной' вариант. При входе в функцию, имя которой должно появиться в списке логгера, вызовем My_set_fname(fname), а для печати My_logger(message); fname ДОЛЖНА быть локальной переменной (располагаться в стеке программы).

My_set_fname(fname) будет вести свой стек (например, связанный список в куче или достаточно большой статический массив (собственно большой - это если My_set_fname() будут вызываться из рекурсии)). В этот стек надо помещать адрес параметра (fname). Здесь надо иметь в виду, что стек исполнения программы растет от больших адресов к меньшим, поэтому при очередном вызове My_set_fname() будем корректировать (путем удаления) верхнюю часть своего стека, так чтобы в нем содержались только адреса больше, чем адрес нашего аргумента. Эти соображения определяют требование к размещению аргумента.
Константы и куча не подходят.

Ну, логика My_logger(), по-моему, уже очевидна (или скажем так: формат вывода - дело вкуса).

Comment: Это некоторые незначительные нюансы реализации. Главная задача заключается в определении, к какой функции принадлежит инструкция, то есть определение начала функции по ссылке в неё. Так как обычно процедуры нелинейные, то без раскрытия всех ветвлений это невозможно.

Answer (score 5):

Есть такой макрос: `__FUNCTION__`, который возвращает имя функции, в которой вызван. Думаю, можно составить макрос, который неявно этот параметр будет конечной функции и передавать.

Можете посмотреть и другие макросы в статье: [Predefined Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(v=VS.100).aspx).

Comment: Я пользуюсь gcc, но за ссылку спасибо.

Comment: В gcc это тоже прекрасно работает =)

ня: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Function-Names.html

Answer (score 2):

Это бактрейс. В стеке - цепочка стековых фреймов (для stdcall-конвенций), в которых адреса возврата из функций. Нормально данная задача не может быть решена без применения графов. Все искомые функции описываются графом, затем получив адрес возврата из стека, находится часть графа, в которой описана инструкция по этому адресу. Далее можно найти начало процедуры и соответственно её имя. Для не stdcall конвенций необходимо вычислять баланс стека при бактрейсе, это если движок, создающий граф, не ведёт список процедур. Для x86 есть готовый движок.

В NT такое логгирование используется очень часто, например, бактрейс - это первое действие при анализе крэшдампов. Есть полноценные апи для работы с бактрейсом (напр. RtlLogStackBackTrace() etc.) и утилиты для его просмотра (UMDH, WinDbg etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Обычно используют макрос `__FUNCTION__` (макрос не входит в стандарт ANSI, но поддерживается основными компиляторами). Например, если функция log, выводящая в лог ошибки, подобна printf, то печать такова

```
log("Error: %s - %s", __FUNCTION__, "not enough memory");
```

Кроме того, стандарт ANSI включает в себя полезные предопределенные макросы:

- `__FILE__` - имя исходного файла,
- `__LINE__` - строка исходного файла.

Answer (score 1):

Очевидного решения не видится. Можно сделать скрипт (например, на Питоне), который будет проходить перед компиляцией по всему коду и оборачивать все функции особенным образом, так чтобы при вызове любой функции устанавливалась глобальная переменная, куда помещалось бы значение `__FUNCTION__`. Например, было

```
void outer() {
    inner();
}
```

А стало:

```
char *previous = NULL;
char *last = NULL;

void outer() {
    previous = last;
    last = __FUNCTION__;
    inner();
    last = previous;
}
```

Сама печать вместо `__FUNCTION__` будет использовать `last`;

```
/* 
 *   Должна распечатать
 *   Error: outer - not enough memory
 */
void inner() {
    printf("Error: %s - not enough memory", last);
}
```